# Error in action space for creating gymnasium environment

Tags: gym

While trying to use a created environment, I get the following error:
`AssertionError: action space does not inherit from gym.spaces.Space, actual type: <class 'gymnasium.spaces.discrete.Discrete'>`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Programming questions or questions about specific software are off-topic here, so your question is off-topic here. We focus on the theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, it was because of inconsistency between using `gym` and `gymnasium`. Uniformly using `gymnasium` seems to resolve all issues.